# Rails: Error missing template when redirecting to original 404 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's my problem.

In my controller, I check that the params given in the URL is a valid user, **IF NOT** I want the visitor to be redirected to the "classic" 404 page. Here's my controller :

```
def home
  @user = User.find_by_domain(params[:domain])

  if !@user.nil?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # home.html.erb
    end
    else
      render(:file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false)
    end
end
```

Yet, when the `@user` is `nil` I get the following error:

`Template is missing
Missing template D:/Project/public/404.html with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths`

I didn't modify the 404 page that Rails generates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
    <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one, may it help you, Thx

```
if !@user.nil?
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # home.html.erb
 end
else
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end
```

I've rails apps and this is my way to handle 404, inside my application_controller.rb i've code like :

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_error
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_not_found
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :render_not_found
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_not_found
end

private
def render_not_found(exception)
  render :template =>"/error/404", :status => 404
end

def render_error(exception)
  render :template =>"/error/500", :status => 500
end
```

And inside config/environments/development.rb make sure:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

Comment: It just changes the error to `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Controller#home` .. Still doesn't redirect me to 404. :s

Comment: hmm, what about your development.rb inside config/environments directory, make sure config.consider_all_requests_local is true

Comment: I ended up doing it differently (custom 404 page) but your solution works too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

1) Inside your ApplicationController add:

```
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    render_404
  end

  def render_404
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render "errors/404", :status => '404 Not Found', :layout => false }
      format.xml  { render :nothing => true, :status => '404 Not Found' }
    end
    true
  end
```

2) Inside the Views folder create a sub folder called "**errors**"

3) Copy your current 404.html file into the new "views/errors" folder and rename it "**404.html.erb**"

Side Note:

Personally, I like to create custom 404 content and then use the application's layout. I prefer to render 500 errors this way too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll switch to that for custom 404 errors. I'm just surprised that I get errors for trying to use original 404 error. Anyways, thanks again.